# Remove Semicolons as Line Delimiters Reading csv-file Using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I'm working with a pandas dataframe that I want to plot. Instead of being float numbers, some values inside the dataframe are strings because they have a semicolon.
This causes a `ValueError` when the dataframe is to be plotted. I have found out that the semicolons only occur at the end of each line.

Is there a keyword in the `read_csv` method to let pandas recognize the semicolons so they can be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the semicolon is being used to separate lines, you can use the `lineterminator` parameter to correctly parse the file:

```
pd.read_csv(..., lineterminator=";")
```

[Pandas CSV documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)

Comment: Ok as I see the semicolons are used as delimiters after each row in my csv-file. Is there a keyword for it in the read_csv-function?

Comment: Updated my answer based on your discovery. If this works for you, can you update your original question to reflect the root of your issue so that others with a similar issue in the future can easily find it?